# Indexing HTML in Solr DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm currently using the JdbcDataSource to import document from a SqlServer backend.  Some of the fields have raw HTML in them.  I would like to strip the HTML before indexing.  The problem is that something is encoding the opening '<' char when indexing.  Ultimately, I'd like to use the HTMLStripTransformer to strip out all the HTML from the JobDescription field, however, it doesn't strip anything because the half encoded content doesn't look like html to it.

### data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME;databaseName=DBNAME;integratedSecurity=true;"
            applicationName="RHW_Jobs SOLR Data Import Handler"/>
<document>
    <entity name="job" query="SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
        SELECT [JobID],[JobDescription] FROM [JobSeeker].[Solr].[Jobs]"
    transformer="HTMLStripTransformer,RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
        <field column="JobID" name="JobID" />
        <field column="JobDescription" name="JobDescription" stripHTML="true" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

### Output from debug window

```
<lst>
<arr name="JobID">
<str>373E383A-AD6C-4858-B5FB-C724486B186A</str>
</arr>
<arr name="JobDescription">
<str>&lt;td class="form">  &lt;ul>    &lt;li>      &lt;p>        &lt;span style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA">&lt;strong>&lt;u> 
...
```

In the DB the JobDescription column has the following:

```
<td class="form">  <ul>    <li>      <p>        <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-bidi-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the HtmlStripFormatter is not processing your data when it is being importted ad you should not have any html markup in your indexed field. I checked the documentation for the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) and noticed that is states the following:

> Note -- The transformer value has to be fully qualified classname .If the class package is 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport' the package name can be omitted. The solr. also works if the class belongs to one of the 'solr' packages . This rule applies for all the pluggable classes like DataSource , EntityProcessor and Evaluator.

Based on that you need to fully qualify the entry in your tranformer attribute, since HTMLStripFormatter comes from the *org.apache.solr.analysis* class. Therefore, you need to modify  as follows:

```
 <entity name="job" query="SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SELECT [JobID],[JobDescription] FROM [JobSeeker].[Solr].[Jobs]"
transformer="org.apache.solr.analysis.HTMLStripTransformer,RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer">
```

Alternately, you could apply the [HtmlStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) to your fieldType for the JobDescription field in your index and let the index remove the Html when it is analyzing the field.

Comment: As far as I can tell the HtmlStripCharFilterFactory will only strip the HTML from the indexed field not the stored field.  Is that correct?  If so that won't work as we display the stored field.  I will look into the full qualification of the name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the semi-encoded results I was observing were just the output from the 'debug' console.  The DIH debug console must partially encode the HTML so that it is viewable and doesn't render.  Additionally, it appears that the HTMLStripTransformer works as advertised.  The issue I was running into is that it isn't very tolerant of bad HTML, such as that spit out by MS Word.  After reindexing with the HtmlStripTransformer enabled there were still a few records with HTML, but it appears those just had bad HTML (ie. attributes whose values weren't enclosed in single quotes, etc).